# Styling Django error message and field label in template

Tags: css, django-forms, django-templates

I am a bit new to styling django templates and am looking to style certain default Django templating function. It seems like the formatting of {{ form }} is encapsulated somewhere else.

1.Currently, Django error message above the field where the error has occurred. How does one move the error message to below the form field?

```
Current:
    This field is required.
    [field]

Desire:
    [field]
    This field is required.
```

2.Currently the field label is to the left of the form field. Is it possible to style it above the form field?

```
Current:
    Username: [field]

Desire:
    Username:
    [field]
```

Thanks.

My template looks like this:

```
 {% block title %}{% trans "title" %}{% endblock %}

 {% block content %}

 {% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'sites/css/style.css' %}" />

 <form action="" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you show your template? Likely you don’t want to use just `{{form}}`, but something more like this:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="submit-link-row">{{ field.label_tag }} <br> {{ field }}</div>
        {% if form.errors %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p class="error-message">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="submit-link-row"><input class="button" type="submit" value="submit"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question with my template.  So your solution means that I essentially have to take apart the default {{ form }} function from Django?

Comment: If you want fine-grained control over how it renders, I think you do, yes.